# sqlite3 change column default value

Tags: sqlite

How do I change the default value of an existing column in a table in sqlite3?

I have a table named `notes` with a boolean column named `hidden`. The default is set to true, I want to set it to false.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

## New Versions

SQLite now supports RENAME COLUMN, ADD COLUMN, and DROP COLUMN so you can change a column default by:

1. Renaming the column: `alter table t rename column c to c_old`
2. Adding the column with the new default value: `alter table t add c boolean default false`
3. Copying the data: `update t set c = c_old`
4. Removing the old column: `alter table t drop column c_old`

Thanks to [dr fu manchu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1680089/dr-fu-manchu) for a heads up on SQLite updating their ALTER TABLE support.

## Older Versions

I don't think you can without replacing the whole table. From the [fine manual](http://www.sqlite.org/omitted.html):

> **SQL Features That SQLite Does Not Implement**
>
> **Complete ALTER TABLE support**
> Only the RENAME TABLE and ADD COLUMN variants of the ALTER TABLE command are supported. Other kinds of ALTER TABLE operations such as DROP COLUMN, ALTER COLUMN, ADD CONSTRAINT, and so forth are omitted.

So there is no way to modify an existing column in SQLite. I think you'll have to create a new table with the appropriate default for `hidden`, copy all the data over, drop the original `notes` table, and then [rename the new one](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html).

Comment: One point might help in this regard. Before running `drop table <table_name>` make sure you run `.dump` and get the schema dump and data as well. You can then use it to create the modified schema quickly and ingest the data.

Comment: Now, in November 2023, the SQLite manual says: "Only the RENAME TABLE, ADD COLUMN, RENAME COLUMN, and DROP COLUMN variants of the ALTER TABLE command are supported. Other kinds of ALTER TABLE operations such as ALTER COLUMN, ADD CONSTRAINT, and so forth are omitted." That means you can add a new column, copy the data, drop the old column and rename the new column now. No need for a separate table anymore.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about that @drfumanchu

Comment: Well, unfortunately I found out that the add column/copy data/rename columns/drop column method only works when there are now views or triggers on that table. I had to drop all related views and triggers an recreate them afterwards, otherwise they were broken.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new database with the same schema (but your new default value), attach both, and migrate.

> For deleting columns or other changes that aren't supported by the "ALTER TABLE" syntax, I create a new table, migrate date into it, drop the old table, and rename the new table to the original name.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/998652/1020467

https://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html

Answer (score -1):

SQLite database browser allows you to drop columns, so you could drop the column with it, and then manually add the column with the default using the sqlite3 command line tool.

Comment: Unfortunately to accomplish this it probably performs all kind of shenanigans under the hood like creating a temp table :| http://stackoverflow.com/q/805363/32453

Answer (score -1):

A viable way to handle modifiable default values is to store the default values in another table. Read from that table prior to performing an insert operation to get the current default. This way the default value is just plain-ole-data in the database instead of part of the schema.