# Best strategy for db update when updating application

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, sqlite

I have function that initialize my database create tables etc.
Now I prepare version two of the application and in this function at the end I added check for column existence and if not exist I alter table.

My question is:
To avoid checking this all the time is it good to put in `UserDefaults` some flag that indicate that current app is version two and if it is to avoid this code?
This seams logical to me but other opinion is always welcome ;)

Comment: Which DB you are using??

Comment: local sqlite database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a version number table/column in your database which stores the schema version number. Every time you change the schema, increment the number in your application file and then run the relevant migration code to get from one schema version to another whilst updating the schema version in the database.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/998652/846698) has a handy way of tracking db schema version numbers without creating a separate table in SQLite

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can user `NSUSER Default` to check this. I don't think anything wrong with this.